# Typescript Mixins for Objects not Classes

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have two domains (in case it's important, the domain objects are not serialized or persisted in anyway and I might be able to keep them totally immutable.):

```js
export interface Foo {
  readonly fooField: string;
  readonly fooMethod: () => string;
}

class FooImpl implements Foo {
  constructor(public readonly fooField: string) {}
  readonly fooMethod = () => "foo";
}

export interface Bar {
  readonly barMethod: () => string;
}

class BarImpl implements Bar {
  readonly barMethod = () => "bar";
}
```

Now imagine there's a One-to-One relationship between `Foo` and `Bar`. To support lazy loading we might have something like this to load `Foo` domain:

```js
type WithBar = { readonly bar: true };
type With = { readonly bar?: true; };
type LoadingOptions = { readonly with?: With; };
```

We have different interfaces for when `Foo` has `Bar` loaded:

```js
export interface FooWithBar {
  readonly fooWithBarMethod: () => string;
}

class FooWithBarImpl implements FooWithBar {
  constructor(readonly bar: Bar) {}
  readonly fooWithBarMethod = () => `${this.bar.barMethod()} in FooWithBar`;
}

// There might be other domains!
export interface FooWithEverything extends FooWithBar {
  readonly fooWithEverythingMethod: () => string;
}

class FooWithEverythingImpl implements FooWithEverything {
  constructor(private readonly bar: FooWithBar) {}
  readonly fooWithEverythingMethod = () =>
    `${this.bar.fooWithBarMethod()} in fooWithEverythingMethod`;
}

function load<O extends LoadingOptions>(options: O): Foo &
  (O["with"] extends WithBar ? FooWithBar : {}) &
  (O["with"] extends WithBar ? FooWithEverything : {})
function load<O extends LoadingOptions>(options: O) {
  const foo: Foo = new FooImpl("foo");

  const bar = options.with?.bar ? new FooWithBarImpl(new BarImpl()) : undefined;
  const all = bar ? new FooWithEverythingImpl(bar) : undefined;

  return {
    ...foo,
    ...bar,
    ...all,
  };
}
```

Which gives us:

```js
const foo1 = load({});
console.log(foo1.fooMethod()); // foo

const foo2 = load({ with: { bar: true } });
console.log(foo2.fooMethod()); // foo
console.log(foo2.fooWithBarMethod()); // bar in fooWithBarMethod

const foo4 = load({ with: { bar: true, /* baz: true */ } });
console.log(foo4.fooMethod()); // foo
console.log(foo4.fooWithBarMethod()); // bar in fooWithBarMethod
console.log(foo4.fooWithEverythingMethod()); // bar in fooWithBarMethod in fooWithEverythingMethod
```

TSC is happy and the behavior is as expected.

Now, my question is, is there any flow or gotcha in the above implementation? Is there any better way to achieve the above with type-safety and code-reusability? Specifically, should I use Mixins feature instead of passing `bar` and `bar` instances into `FooWithEverythingImpl`. (If yes, some guidance would be highly appreciated. Thanks.)
Here's the playground (with more domains, removed from here to keep the code small.) [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgMQgjgG8AoOOKYTAEwiQBsBPOdI-BYR2gLjgDOMKMgDmAbgpUa9Jq3YQAssBgALCHzgAKAJRwAvAD5BwsZIC%20ZMtkaYBAgkQCSAWzCNEbxsBfAUDwmJySmwGISgAV2wYaC0wCIAjRgRsaToGFjYOLh5%20cLE9EktKanS5LKUVdVoDbT0jODUEAQA6BU5uWgsrUEhYRBQ0LFw4ACFMKFIpUtlMhInlNQ1%20XQNjfKQJMktrW3sxidd3T3cfPxgHccngtNnWeahF6trVhoAiB7fusl7oeGRUBgcHhxgAvKYlGQZe6YUFPZZ1NYmESbb42OyXWFHDwILxnfwHcE3GbQuDzOFVDQverGD6wr7bHrgP4DQHDPCBADqCDUVwht1JCm5vIWlM0r3WplRjN2GMcEGFqiu2JO3l8BK5PKVE35oSQ4SiMSgWhJ5Qe-CuhWKAvKQq1V3hNX0iIaAAMACQkJqtB4tB6O3TmAYVRUOsWu76-foAobA%20Wh2H802ZO0iilLcU05FmGXo-aatMq3GndUXeP2xM3PUG6KxZMw0EW2FW6ZQ21EBPp57OiVwD1e1TNP2w4ddjSB4Op7Vj2gRmVR-6DIEjAuqACiADc0Mwmpsk22Ux2tZvt7vRI6VlmNlsdnmAke1CeoDvB5si3jS-eFcet8%20z7qwmEQ1YikSgwBEDdMFQG1DwgfhAgAGlAuBwIQSDoPrMkJngh9tSgJDKDAiCoLwTDyRw780wIuAW0hMpYMVJ8XzER1qTWZD%2029YcoDaXCwwzCdMCQGpPS48leMo6cAx0cw5x2GBmDAPAE0mZ0SBgmEoH4IC8HMSQFKUuBO1qdSyNhbTIl0-TFOUrUTNbejNIAfgsiJgEkOi7iw0EXMaSyLEkMgDLwAAZCA6DEAB5MAYAQMJ7M80kAHctV8xUAqsdAIiQaI4qQOBGHC2gAB5IrgUBUGEhwwoizZotisJDC0KQIBivKBH4SKkJ0Ci4AAMikLRIoAbTeFK1DeABdcqQEq2gHBUuAnPLEVJn4Io9AGyghtG8bVCmma5oWitwWW1cwTgdbzE2waRrGrUDoqvx5qMitJj6160yWlb11-Zi9yunRJCynKGvywq6FKw7nuqoqoraxqtFasGOrgSLCikat4AUXrnSQYAkvlbEtDeBQ3iBqwQkArCtJ%20vkAB84Gy2hgHQZBgCdOBkfalo9qc7jkOW-HCfOw4vC0YWDigYmdB0ZD%20GZ1n2a6Sm4Cx7yKOMxnFbZ-HOe5sJedS0dBbgSXRdBYnJbBGW5cIy6meEpW9cCqn9XgTBGEYTWf1PV9RDgbWnd1jmDGQh5%20o%208lvvN3CmLPYmFAQmnk-JPQFeD5XXekGAIigfKbkoFpi6T5Di%2046ii%20L8lK7gcvPcYai9NzamFAARlqCHaC0DbJGrCBvBaQrRC0duJOkoG4AAeiniorHVhQACZO6Knu4D29aadc3S4GuvuwgH4Ah4gEel-HsVdEnme5-7wfh9HohF4klSJ-EafZ4j5AQzex159bogADMK86Brw3qQDWfk3K713hTW%20R974KAAefASss37XwUNYA%20d8T4PwgEgqcYJX7v28pOPisJf6YPdhUAALMA7u6kwHqXNJA4AqdzIsOgXvShAhD7H1PkQahyDqiXzQbPDBcC%20G4MEQQ0UKCr4fx1F-GRjwxTcN4QggRz8TpEOvtHJRZCZxqOwfwiA0i45-TPDohRkx9GSX4s8ISNQ9H5RkYYoAA).

Comment: Is this a code review question? It *might* be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com than here (but I'm not recommending you migrate this there as-is; they have [their own rules for what's appropriate](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and this seems too hypothetical as stated).  For Stack Overflow, this code seems to be a little long and the question doesn't have an obvious issue you're trying to solve.

Comment: Yeah thought about it. I can try to reduce the code if that helps. Or will move it there.

Comment: It would not be [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on CR in the current form because it [is missing context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652) in terms of what the code achieves.

Comment: OK, I'll try to simplify it more.